# 500 Internal Server Error in ajax request in socialengine's advanced search plugin

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, mootools, socialengine

[image: there is 500 internal server error when i searched pa]I am using a advanced search plugin. When I search with "Maria" or anything else its working fine, but when I search "pa"  It gives me 500 internal server error. It's working fine with other queries. I have tried searching other words its working.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);    
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_STRICT);



// Create application, translate, view
$application = Engine_Api::getInstance()->getApplication();
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('translate');
$view = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_View');

// $view->layout()->staticBaseUrl = $_REQUEST['static_base_url'];
// $view->layout()->staticBaseUrl = base64_decode($_REQUEST['static_base_url']);
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setBaseUrl(
        base64_decode($_REQUEST['static_base_url']));

//$wView = ( (preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', @$_REQUEST['pageGlobalSearch']) == 1) ? true : false );
$wView=false;
// TO DO HERE
try {

    $coresearchApi = Engine_Api::_()->getApi('search', 'core');
    $values = $_REQUEST;

    $query = $values['search'];
    $trimquery = trim($query);
    if ($trimquery == null)
        exit();



    $item_per_page = $values['maxre'];
    // get types from selected modules in back-end
    $searchModulesTable = new Ynadvsearch_Model_DbTable_Modules();
    $enabled_types = $searchModulesTable->getAllEnabledTypes(null, $wView);
    $types = array();
    foreach ($enabled_types as $module_types) {
        foreach ($module_types as $module_type) {
            $types[] = $module_type;
        }
    }

    $paginator = Engine_Api::_()->getApi('search', 'ynadvsearch')->getPaginator(
            $query, $types, null, null);

    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($item_per_page);
    $data = array();

    if (count($paginator) == 0) {
        $data[] = array(
                'key' => $query,
                'label' => $view->translate('No results were found'),
                'type' => 'no_result_found_link',
                'url' => $view->url(
                        array(


                        ), 'ynadvsearch_search', true) . '?is_search=1&query=' . $query
        );
    } else {
        $data[] = array(
                'key' => $query,
                'label' => 'Hidden choice',
                'url' => $view->url(
                        array(


                        ), 'ynadvsearch_search', true) . '?is_search=1&query=' . $query,
                'type' => 'hidden_link'
        );
        if (count($paginator) < $item_per_page) {

            $temp_data = array();
            foreach ($paginator as $item) {
                if (! $item) {
                    continue;
                }
                $type = $item['type'];

                $item = Engine_Api::_()->getItem($type, $item['id']);

                if (! $item) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (! is_object($item)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (! $item instanceof Core_Model_Item_Abstract) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!$item->getIdentity()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($type == 'user') {
                    if ($item->verified != 1 || $item->enabled != 1 ||
                             $item->approved != 1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (! isset($temp_data[$type])) {
                    $temp_data[$type] = array();
                }
                if ($type == 'activity_action') {
                    $label = $item->body;
                } else {
                    $label = $item->getTitle();
                }
                $photo_url = $view->itemPhoto($item, 'thumb.icon');
                $photo_url = preg_replace('/\/index.php/', '', $photo_url);

                $temp_data[$type][] = array(
                        'photo' => $photo_url,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'url' => $item->getHref(),
                        'type' => $type,
                        'type_label' => $view->translate(getLabelType($type))
                );
            }

            foreach ($temp_data as $item_type) {
                foreach ($item_type as $item) {
                    $data[] = $item;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $temp_data = array();

            foreach ($paginator as $item) {
                if (! $item) {
                    continue;
                }
                $type = $item['type'];

                $item = Engine_Api::_()->getItem($type, $item['id']);
                if (! $item) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (! is_object($item)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (! $item instanceof Core_Model_Item_Abstract) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!$item->getIdentity()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($type == 'user') {
                    if ($item->verified != 1 || $item->enabled != 1 ||
                             $item->approved != 1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (! isset($temp_data[$type])) {
                    $temp_data[$type] = array();
                }
                if ($type == 'activity_action') {
                    $label = $item->body;
                } else {
                    $label = $item->getTitle();
                }

                $photo_url = $view->itemPhoto($item, 'thumb.icon');
                $photo_url = preg_replace('/\/index.php/', '', $photo_url);
                $temp_data[$type][] = array(
                        'photo' => $photo_url,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'url' => $item->getHref(),
                        'type' => $type,
                        'type_label' => $view->translate(getLabelType($type))
                );
            }

            foreach ($temp_data as $item_type) {
                foreach ($item_type as $item) {
                    $data[] = $item;
                }
            }

            // $itemnum = $item_per_page;
            $itemnum = ($item_per_page > count($data)) ? count($data) : $item_per_page;
            while (count($data) < $item_per_page) {
                $itemnum ++;
                $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($itemnum);
                $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
                $item = $paginator->getItem($itemnum);
                if (! $item) {
                    break;
                }
                $type = $item['type'];

                $item = Engine_Api::_()->getItem($type, $item['id']);
                if (! $item) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!$item->getIdentity()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($type == 'user') {
                    if ($item->verified != 1 || $item->enabled != 1 ||
                             $item->approved != 1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (! isset($temp_data[$type])) {
                    $temp_data[$type] = array();
                }
                if ($type == 'activity_action') {
                    $label = $item->body;
                } else {
                    $label = $item->getTitle();
                }

                $photo_url = $view->itemPhoto($item, 'thumb.icon');
                $photo_url = preg_replace('/\/index.php/', '', $photo_url);
                $data[] = array(
                        'photo' => $photo_url,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'url' => $item->getHref(),
                        'type' => $type,
                        'type_label' => $view->translate(getLabelType($type))
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $data[] = array(
            'key' => $query,
            'label' => $view->translate('Search more results'),
            'url' => $view->url(
                    array(

                    ), 'ynadvsearch_search', true) . '?is_search=1&query=' . $query,
            'type' => 'see_more_link'
    );

    echo Zend_Json::encode($data);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}

function getLabelType ($type)
{
    return strtoupper('ITEM_TYPE_' . $type);
}
```

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you add a jsFiddle with your problem in it? or a live link, or your source code relevant to this problem...

Comment: I have updated my question please check again and help me.

Comment: Do you have a link to a live page? Do you have any client-side code interfering with the search/ajax query?

Comment: yes. you can go to [link](eyando.net) and login with asif@yahoo.com password is 123456. its testing account, on top you will se search box. try to search any string like maria you will see results, but try to search patrick or just pa you will see nothing...but if you see network requests it shows 500 error with "pa" please help me.

Comment: Had some time to check your site now. I did check the search box and found no error(!). If I search `p` i get some results, if I search `pa`I get no results and no error, if I search `pal` I get for example Palestrina's beautiful Stabat Matter that I played many times with my string-quartet :) So no error for me. Can you post a image of what happens to you?

Comment: you can see the errors in network requests...let me send you screenshot.

Comment: please see attached image.

Answer (score 0):

For 500 internal issue on SocialEngine, it relates to PHP error. Just check the php error log and you will see more details about this issue.

Hope this help.